# Accessing same db.session across different modules with flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask-sqlachemy. I declare a `db` object to attach to the flask app:

in __init__.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
..
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Now I use `db` in `views`, and sqlalchemy managing setup and teardown of `db.session`. I then call a method in `business`, which **also** accesses `db.session`.

Does SQLAlchemy grant the **same session** to caller and callee methods even though they are in different modules? I worry `views` and `business` sees different sessions when they access `db.session`.

---

in views.py

```
from myapp import db
from business import check_dude

@app.route("/csrf_test", methods=['GET'])
def csrf_test_form():
    dude = db.session.query(...)
    flag = check_dude( dude)
```

in business.py

```
from myapp import db
def check_dude( dude):
    x = db.session.query(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: You should be ok.

The code here is the key

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

You are binding the `db` to specific `app` instance of Flask. Technically, you can also do:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

and then later in other places

```
db.init_app(app)
```

So, Flask-SQLAlchemy allows you do bind the entire app right away or later on.

As long you have put the `db` declaration in `__init__.py`, i would say you are safe to re-use it any module.